# Selenium ChromeDriver c# - Not working Click

Tags: c#, selenium, testing, selenium-chromedriver

I am working with Selenium to do some tests in my application and the functions which are using the method "Click" are not working fine since two days ago.

For example, the simple function to check the login:

```
public LoginConnect() : base() { }

    #region pageElements
    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "userNameInput")]
    public IWebElement userId { get; set; }

    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "userPasswordInput")]
    public IWebElement password { get; set; }

    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "LoginButton")]
    public IWebElement loginButton { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region pageActions
    public JobList LogConnect(String userId, String password)
    {            
        CleanFormConnect();
        this.userId.SendKeys(userId);
        this.password.SendKeys(password);            
        this.loginButton.Click();
        return new JobList();
    }
}
```

It's not working fine. There is no errors in the function Click, but the browser doesn't do anything.

The version of Chrome is Versión 61.0.3163.100
The version of Driver is 2.33

If I change the function

```
this.loginButton.Click();
```

for

```
this.loginButton.SendKeys(Keys.Return);
```

It works as expected.

Comment: so, your code hasnt changed, and this was working. has anything else changed at all? Has chrome updated, what about in other browsers

Comment: Also, have you checked the console output of the browser too so see if there are any error messages

Comment: No changes in the code and no changes in the version of Browser. In fact, the test is not failing in that function. The test fails in the next instruction because it's not able to find the next element because the login has not been ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue adding a code to manage the click through JavaScript.

```
 public static void JsClick (IWebElement element)
    {
        IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)ContextDriver.GetDriver();
        js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same thing... click was working, then suddenly no more, although the code hasn't changed.

Turned out I have played with the zoom percentage in Chrome - and the webdriver clicks only work with 100% zoom setting. This is already tracked as an issue:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=628